# How to connect private instance under public instance via LAN in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

i'm create two instance public & private. And create two network interface for public instance. network interface one attach with internet gateway & second network interface is connected to private EC2 instance WAN. Also tried to attach private EC2 instance under public EC2 instance using route table. but private instance WAN can't connect with public instance LAN. Also, i'm create one NAT gateway in public subnet and attach with private route table able to connect internet in private instance but can not connect with public instance network. Help me to access public instance internet in private instance via public LAN.

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Groups associated with these instances? Is there a particular reason why you have created a second Network Interface?

Answer (score 0):

All subnets can communicate with each other by default in an Amazon VPC.

You do not need to create a second network interface.

Instances always communicate via private IP addresses. The public IP address is only implemented inside the Internet Gateway. (It might *look* like an instance has a public IP address, but that is added as a Reverse NAT in the Internet Gateway.)

Make sure that the security groups permit access for the instances to communicate with each other.